# SSRS Filter using Column Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have two columns in a dataset `LABELSTRING` and `FIELDVALUE` namely. The sample values are as follow.

```
LABELSTRING FIELDVALUE
--          -- 
FIRSTNAME   ALEX
LASTNAME    FERGIE
CITY        MANCHESTER
```

Now I need to get the values of `FIRSTNAME`, `LASTNAME` & `CITY` in my report and present them in a text box. Is there any way I can do it. I am pretty new to this stuff.

Thanks

Comment: Tell me if I am getting your question right. Those 3 records are in a table for the person named "Alex" and there'll be 3 such records for every person, and you want 'em all displayed in your report? Like how exactly? You could put 'em in a tablix.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change your dataset query so that FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, and CITY are the names of the columns and there is 1 row returned with the values. Then in a textbox you could use a formula like this:

```
=First(Parameters!FIRSTNAME.Value, "DataSet1") + " " + First(Parameters!LASTNAME.Value, "DataSet1") + " " + First(Parameters!CITY .Value, "DataSet1")
```

Another option is to keep the existing dataset and use calculated fields to get the values you need. This method is a little more messy, but can be useful in more complex situations. First you add a calculated field using an expression like this:

```
=iif(Fields!LABELSTRING.Value = "FIRSTNAME", Fields!FIELDVALUE.Value, Nothing)
```

Then, in the textbox you can refer to them like this:

```
=Max(Parameters!CALCULATED_FIRSTNAME.Value, "DataSet1")
```